# Binance API error. ImportError: No module named binance.client

Tags: python, binance

I have imported the Binance package. I don't understand why it is not working. Can someone please point out what is wrong? This is my first time using an API and importing the necessary files.

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *
import apiKey

client = Client(apiKey.apiKey ,apiKey.apiSecurity)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BinanceTrader.py", line 1, in <module>
    from binance.client import Client
ImportError: No module named binance.client
```

Comment: Well, did you actually install this package first?

Comment: yes, I have. It has worked on another program but now isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you've installed package `python-binance` ?

If not try this `pip install python-binance`

For more securable and comfortable method is `virtual environment`. You should look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

---

### Setting Up Virtual Environment

1. open the command-line
2. `cd <path-your-project-root-folder>`
3. `python -m venv env`
4. `source env/bin/activate` (Linux or MacOS) or `.\env\Scripts\activate` (Windows)
5. install dependencies (in your case) `pip install python-binance`
6. save the dependencies `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
7. run your code!

Comment: I have installed the package. It has previously worked on another file but now isn't working on that file or the new file I'm working on. Does there a specific action I need to do? I did previously write it in a text editor and then move it to VS code. Could that affect it?

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried to explain step by step how to setting up the virtual environment. I hope you' ll be able to using without any problems. If it doesn't work, please googling for virtual env. stuff I'm sure that there are many tutorials and explanation on this topic. Happy hacking! 